# What does :+= method do defined for scala.collection.immutable.Vector?

Tags: scala

given the following scala code:

```
var v1 = Vector("foo")
v1 :+= ""
```

What does `:+=` do, how is it different from `+=` and where is it defined?

Thanks!

PS: Yes, i did search on this, but didn't found anything. Found trough this (http://simply.liftweb.net/index-2.3.html#prev) tutorial.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Scala sequences have three operators that produce new sequences by adding something to an old sequence: `++`, `+:` and `:+`. The `++` operator simply concatenates a Scala sequence with another (or a traversable). The other two prepend and append elements, respectively.

The peculiar syntax of `+:` and `:+` is due to the way they are used. Any operator ending with `:` applies to the object on the *right*, not on the left. That is:

```
1 +: Seq.empty == Seq.empty.+:(1)
```

By symmetry, the other operator is `:+`, though the colon is meaningless in that case. This let you write things like this:

```
scala> 1 +: 2 +: 3 +: Seq.empty :+ 4 :+ 5 :+ 6
res2: Seq[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
```

Note how the elements being added end up in the exact same position as they appear in the expression. This makes it easier to visualize what's happening.

Now, you have `:+=`, not any of the above. As it happens, Scala allows one to concatenate any operator with `=` to make up a get-and-set operation. So the common increment expression:

```
x += 1
```

Actually means

```
x = x + 1
```

Likewise,

```
v1 :+= ""
```

means

```
v1 = v1 :+ ""
```

which creates a new vector by appending the empty string to the old vector, and then assigns it to `v1`.

Comment: Excellent answer.  This commit makes them extractors/unapply(), as well as sequence composers: https://github.com/scala/scala/commit/b3efb3d493605d1c7e106e5f0a697b52ebb3d97c

Comment: Thanks, got it! Scala is really crazy, once i understood something, it feels like never wanting to go back to java .... but lets see ;-)

Comment: For completeness, there is nothing like `+=:` ?

Comment: You can check scalex.org search engine to see if a "symbolic operator" exists http://scalex.org/

Comment: @thedude There is, on mutable classes. Mutable classes _do_ define `+=`, which _modifies_ the collection instead of returning a new one, and use `+=:` as a counterpart to it. Look at [the scaladoc index](http://www.scala-lang.org/archives/downloads/distrib/files/nightly/docs/library/index.html#index.index-_) for it.

Comment: Thanks for these both references!